# php Regex for date format

Tags: php, regex, date

I have custom date format that looks like:

```
M jS Y g:i a (Feb 23rd 2016 3:32 pm )
```

It's really hard to write regex to that format like this, how I can detect that date have that format ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't need necessarily a regex, just use the `date_create_from_format` function. It returns `FALSE` if it's unable to parse the string, so you can check on its return value.

```
$dateObject = date_create_from_format("M jS Y g:i a", "Feb 23rd 2016 3:32 pm");
if ($dateObject === false) {
    // string is in a wrong format
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The regular expressions **are not** the best solution in your case. PHP already provides good support for date/time parsing from strings.

Use [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) to parse your string. It returns a valid `DateTime` object when the parsing succeeds or `FALSE` when the parsing fails:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat(
    'M jS Y g:i a',
    'Feb 23rd 2016 3:32 pm',
    new DateTimeZone('UTC')        // put your timezone here
);
print_r($date);
```

It displays:

```
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2016-02-23 15:32:00.000000
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => UTC
)
```